# How do I get the value of URL unsafe keys like 'mycc\u0000a' in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, urlencode

I have a database 'myc' with documents, as

```
{
  "total_rows": 3,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [{
    "id": "lscc\u0000mycc",
    "key": "lscc\u0000mycc",
    "value": {
      "rev": "1-35f379c3ea35ef0077b595923bf36151"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "mycc\u0000a",
    "key": "mycc\u0000a",
    "value": {
      "rev": "2-f3049e0b19f6969f01671889c8b1456f"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "statedb_savepoint",
    "key": "statedb_savepoint",
    "value": {
      "rev": "3-62ba0d88e905ef321c85c542bec7bd15"
    }
  }]
}
```

I need to get the value stored in the keys/id like `lscc\u0000mycc` or `mycc\u0000a`.

When the keys are URL safe, we can just call http://localhost:5984/myc/statedb_savepoint. How do I access the same using GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You have to URL-encode the backslashes in your IDs (`%5C`):

http://localhost:5984/myc/lscc%5Cu0000mycc

http://localhost:5984/myc/mycc%5Cu0000a

Comment: I tried URL encoding http://localhost:5984/myc/mycc%5Cu0000a, but still same issue.
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}